# Unbounded knapsack problem - max value per weight approach

Tags: algorithm, knapsack-problem

Problem:
Given a knapsack with weight W and a set of items where each item has a value and weight, find the max value you can pack in the knapsack.

So I have been reading online and all the solutions I saw include DP but I cant understand why.

What I thought of is:

1. for each item find its value per weight
2. pack as much of the item with the highest value per weight as you can in the knapsack
3. If the knapsack is full return the value
4. Otherwise do the same for the next highest value per weight item (assuming there is space for it)
5. Repeat until knapsack is full or we been through all items

This sounds much simpler than DP to me (but maybe its just me).
Is this approach correct? Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you just post your non working code ? It's difficult to comprehend from theory steps. You can try and find an online judge problem and submit your code there. If all goes well, then your approach was correct anyway, if it doesn't then we can trace with the failing test case to understand the problem better